# Двойные кавычки (кавычки в кавычках)

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Допускаются ли в тексте двойные кавычки в подобном случае: **остановка "Гостиница "Москва""**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что вложенные кавычки должны быть разного начертания. Скажем, ёлочки и лапочки. В тех же случаях, когда по техническим соображениям невозможна верстка с разными типами кавычек (на практике - только в электронных текстах типа форумов или чатов), допускается использование кавычек одного стиля. При этом при встрече кавычек разной степени вложенности (как в вашем случае) две кавычки заменяются одной.

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Кавычки только одни.